# Условные конструкции IF ELIF ELSE

Tags: python, условия

Задание:
Написать программу, которая принимает базовое целое число и запрашивает следующее число, большее, чем предыдущее. Если введено большее число, то выводится текст more ok и запрашивается целое число, меньшее, чем базовое, после проверки выводится текст less ok. Иначе в обоих случаях выводится текст error.

Не могу сообразить, как реализовать запрос большего числа от предыдущего.
Заранее благодарю за подсказки

```
base_number = int(input("Введите базовое целое число: "))
next_number = int(input("Введите следующее целое число: "))

if next_number > base_number:
  print("more ok")

new_number = int(input("Введите целое число, меньшее, чем базовое: "))

if new_number < base_number:
 print("less ok")

else:
  print("error")
```

Comment: Покажите что вы уже написали

Comment: @S. Nick поправила вопрос, внесла код, но он работает неправильно, вот так должна реагировать программа на ввод: Входные данные:

5
7
3
Выходные данные:

more ok
less ok
Входные данные:

5
7
9
Выходные данные:

more ok
error
Входные данные:

5
3
Выходные данные:

error
Входные данные:

1
1
Выходные данные:

error
Входные данные:

-3
-1
-6
Выходные данные:

more ok
less ok

Answer (score 0):

```
base_number = int(input("Базовое целое число: "))
next_number = int(input("Следующее целое число, которое больше предыдущего: "))

if next_number > base_number:
    print("more ok")
    new_number = int(input("Введите целое число, меньшее, чем базовое: "))
    if new_number < base_number:
     print("less ok")
    else:
     print("error")
else:
  print("error")
```

Comment: Зря усложняете. В первоначальный код с двумя раздельными ифами добавьте else в первый иф

Comment: @MBo
Спасибо за подсказку, учту. Вчера у меня как-то он неправильно работал с элсе в первом иф...